# Conditional probability problem with two dice

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> We roll two fair dice three times. 
>  (i) What is the probability that we get consecutive sums $6, 8, 4?$ 
>  (ii) What is the probability that we get a sum of $4$ on the third throw if on the first two we get a sum of $8$ and $5$ respectively?  
>  (iii) What is the probability that the three outcomes contain exactly one sum of $4$ and exactly one sum of $10?$

My answer to (i) was: The total probability of getting these sums is: $\frac{5}{36}\cdot\frac{5}{36}\cdot \frac{3}{36}\approx 0.0016$. But I'm not exactly sure how to find the answer to the other two. Does (ii) imply that the throws are somehow conditionally bound? Wouldn't it normally be the probability of getting a sum of $4$ irregardless of what you have thrown before? (so $\frac{3}{36}$). And I'm not sure how to approach the third question aswell. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: You're right about ii), it is the probability of getting $4$ regardless of the outcome of the previous throws. About iii) and using the fact that the outcomes are independent, it should be something like $3!P(X=4)\cdot P(X=10)\cdot P(X\ne 4,X\ne 10)$. The $3!$ accounts for the ordering of the three outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

> Does (ii) imply that the throws are somehow conditionally bound?

That is something you have to determine.  And you did that.

> Wouldn't it normally be the probability of getting a sum of 4 irregardless of what you have thrown before?

Indeed. Each pair of rolls are independent of previous rolls.

> And I'm not sure how to approach the third question as well.

You have the probability for a *particular* roll being 4, 10, or elsewise. Being $3/36$, $3/36$, and $30/36$ respectively.

You should be able to count the arrangements of these three distinct results.  $\{[4,10,E], [4,E, 10],\ldots, [E,10,4]\}$

Go forth and multiply.